# Unable to generate PDF on server (Production Environment)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-gem

I'm converting HTML to PDF using with wicked_pdf and wkhtmltopdf and it's working fine on my localhost but when I deploy that code on server then I'm getting following error on server.

**Error as well as Logs**

```
RuntimeError (Error: Failed to execute:
["/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "-q", "--orientation", "Landscape", "--page-size", "Legal", "--margin-top", "27", "--margin-bottom", "40", "--margin-left", "20", "--margin-right", "20", "--header-spacing", "10", "--header-html", "file:////tmp/wicked_header_pdf20151126-3990-ttmmjg.html", "--footer-spacing", "5", "--footer-html", "file:////tmp/wicked_footer_pdf20151126-3990-6tmvq3.html", "file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20151126-3990-1r6mnm6.html", "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20151126-3990-10ir53b.pdf"]
Error: PDF could not be generated!
 Command Error: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: 1: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf:~: not found
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: 1: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: cannot create ... Directory nonexistent
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: 1: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf:ELF: not found
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: 3: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
):
```

The usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf is present on production server but still getting above error.

Comment: https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/266

Comment: Thanks for reply.. i ll try to solve using ur suggestion @Tachyons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have access to production?

If you have, login with the same user as your application and the run this:

```
ls -t /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

If it does not give you a good result this means your application is pointing to the wrong path.

Cheers

Comment: Great, you can accept it as the answer to your questions so that other users can do the same troubleshooting that you did.